# Editing Font Size of Related Product Titles in WooCommerce

Tags: css, woocommerce, product, customization, font-size

The template we are using (Neve) defaults the product title to a very large text size that doesn't display great with Product names of any decent length.  I have entered the following CSS to counter act that:

`.woocommerce div.product .product_title { font-size: 25px; }`

This has worked a treat for the Product title on the Single Item Pages, however on the related products and recently viewed products the Title is still in an extremely large font.

I would love some help in trying to get this sorted - it just looks ridiculous like its zoomed in on those product titles or something!

Thanks!

Comment: can you try to inspect element on those "zoomed in" elements and see what style rules actually applied to that element?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction for this one - I have been teaching myself so not sure of where to find all the details and didn't realise this details was also available when you inspect.  All fixed now thanks to your help :)